# js - load the same image multiple times

Tags: javascript

This is just for playing with CSS and images. I'm trying to load the same image multiple times (to avoid it loading many times). The above code appends the img only to the last div. Not sure why

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/600/400.jpg";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("div"); 
  div.classList.add("section-"+i);
  div.appendChild(img);
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: You need to create a new image for each iteration otherwise you are just moving the image around the DOM.

Comment: If I create a new instance of Image() in the for loop, would it still request it from the url only once or would it do it multiple times (therefore defeating the purpose of doing it)?

Comment: It should load from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the image on every iteration of the loop, not just once.

By not placing it in the loop you create one instance of the image node, and move that to the new element every time you create a new div and use `appendChild()` and thus not creating a new image element. You are just referencing the original node and moving it.

By creating a new image node on every loop you create a new image node for each div giving the result you desire.

**Note:** If the image is the same it should load from the cache each time.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/600/400.jpg";

  var div = document.createElement("div"); 
  div.classList.add("section-"+i);
  div.appendChild(img);
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine.